# output to file in c++ (replace exist file)

Tags: c++, file, output, fstream

i have a spesific function that write in to text file.
example code:

```
void func(){
     std::fstream myfile("memory.txt", std::ios::app);
     myfile << "some text" << std::endl;
}
```

i want that text will added to file and this is happen.

But if i open the program again so the new text will added to exist text and no replace the old.

How can i replace the old text with new text evrey program running??

mabye i need to use some flags?

thanks.

Comment: but like this the text replace evrey call function

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [`trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) flag so that the content of the file will be discarded.

```
std::fstream myfile("memory.txt", std::ios::trunc);
```

Comment: Don't create std::fstream myfile variable in every func() call, but store it in some global variable, so it is created only once per program run.